# Express-Winston: Write Express Access Logs to File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

Is it possible to only write the access lines from express to a log file, and keep the other logs in the console? Something like this:

```
app.use(expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            colorize: true
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
            name: 'access-file',
            filename: 'access-error.log',
            level: 'info' //This setting is what i need to change for access lines only
        })
    ],
    ignoreRoute: function(req) {
        return (req.url === '/healthcheck');
    },
    meta: false, 
    msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", 
    colorStatus: true
}));
```

The problem is that I do not know how to isolate just the access log lines. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just configure a custom logging level of 'access' and then point it at the file as you like.

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-custom-logging-levels

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this would solve the issue I am having, as express logs are done through express, and I could not control them. therefor, I could not set their log level